# Java format word in string

Tags: java, arraylist

For example I have a text file that contains the contents of each line of a book, I have a java program to search for a particular word in those lines from the book.

This is the program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AliceSearch {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<String> aiw = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("aiw.txt"));
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scan.hasNext()){
            aiw.add(scan.nextLine());
        }

        String searchTerm;

        System.out.print("Please Input Search Parameter : ");

        searchTerm = input.nextLine();

        boolean itemFound = false;

        String currItem = null;

        for(int i = 0; i<aiw.size(); i++  ) {
            currItem = (String)aiw.get(i);

            if (currItem.contains(searchTerm)) {

                matches.add(currItem);

                itemFound = true;

            }
        }

        System.out.println("");

        if ( itemFound == false ) {

            System.out.println ( "No results containing "+searchTerm );

        }else{

            System.out.println ( "We Found the following results : " );

            for(int r = 0; r < matches.size(); r++){
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(matches.get(r));
            }
        }

        scan.close();
        input.close();

    }

}
```

I would like the `searchTerm` from each resultant line to be in uppercase when outputed (or when placed in the matches ArrayList). How would i go about this? I know that you use `.toUpperCase();` but I do not now how i can change one word in a string of words.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Can you use String.replaceAll method like myString.replaceAll("abc", "ABC")

Comment: No, `replace` is the right choice. `replaceAll` involves regular expressions, which OP doesn't need.

Comment: Do not you need to capitalize "City" as well as "city"?

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas I am not sure what you mean..

Comment: He means, you want to replace both "city" and "City" with "CITY".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes i would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of outputting it the way you do it right now:

```
System.out.println(matches.get(r));
```

can't you use

```
System.out.println(matches.get(r).replace(searchTerm, searchTerm.toUpperCase()));
```

Here is the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) for the `replace()` method used to replace the found word with it's uppercase version. It would be better to have

```
String uppercase = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
```

outside of the loop and then use

```
System.out.println(matches.get(r).replace(searchTerm, uppercase));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method on `String` that should fit your use case exactly:

```
line.replace(word, word.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using replace functionality of the pattern. We surely also need to highlight the partially capitalized words (start of the sentence, for instance), so need to create a Pattern with flags, cannot just use `String.replaceAll()`:

```
 Pattern highlight = Pattern.compile(
   Pattern.quote(word), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE );
 String hw = word.toUpperCase();
 line = highlight.matcher(line).replaceAll(hw);
```

The first two lines should be prepared in advance as soon as the word is known. There is no need to recompute them newly for every found line. Pattern.quote quotes reserved characters so they will be given no special meaning.

Comment: This is overly verbose. Why not simply `"(?i)word"`. For extra safety, run word through `Pattern.quote`.

Comment: Yes, this way is also possible.

Comment: Pattern.quote makes a lot of sense