# how to show json array as html in textview

Tags: android

i want to show json in html tag below mycode im getting json and show in two diffrent textview but i want to show in single lines and show all getJSONObject(i).getString("name")); name in bold color and all getJSONObject(i).getString( "sub_ingredients")); in simple text do not want to use two textview i want toshow insingle text view what wil ido? i want to show as html tag

```
              "dish_ingredient":
  [
  {"name":"Salt","sub_ingredients":""},
  {"name":"Sesame Seeds","sub_ingredients":""},
   {"name":"Calcium Sulfate","sub_ingredients":""},
  {"name":"Brown Sugar","sub_ingredients":""},
  {"name":"Salt","sub_ingredients":""},
 {"name":"Hamburger Bun","sub_ingredients":""},
 {"name":"Cheese-cultured pasteurized milk","sub_ingredients":""},
 {"name":"Hamburger Bun","sub_ingredients":"Wheat, Niacin, Eggs"}]}




  final LinearLayout table3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table3);

JSONArray school5 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_ingredient");

  for (int i = 0; i < school5.length(); i++) {

   row4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
  ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(school5

                    .getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.subingredients))

  .setText(school5.getJSONObject(i).getString( "sub_ingredients"));

table3.addView(row4);


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to display the `JSON` as formatted above in one `TextView` but with certain highlighting. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319896/java-format-word-in-string). If you want to keep the `JSON` in its original format I would just get the initial `JSONArray`, call toString(), and then replace the words "name" and "sub-ingredient" with text fomatted the way you want.

If I misunderstood and you want to extract the values for each `JSONObject` you just need to loop through the `JSONArray`

```
//format these to look like whatever you want
SpanableString nameTitle = "Name: "
SpanableString subIngredientTitle = " Sub-ingredient: ";
String concatProduct = "";
int arraySize = jsonArray.length();

for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    JSONObject thing = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = thing.getString("name");
    String subIngredient = thing.getString("sub-ingredient");
    if(i == 0){
        concatProduct = nameTitle + name + subIngredientTitle + subIngredient;
     } else {
        concatProduct += " " + nameTitle + name + subIngredientTitle + subIngredient;
     }
}

textView.setText(concatProduct);
```

Something like this would let you process the `JSONArray` and build one string that you could set to one `TextView`. The formatting is up to you.

Comment: You may have to tweak it I just wrote it in the answer box

Comment: what is  SpanableString

Comment: Lets you format the text. Google it. That way you can have one textview with different words different colors or whatever

Comment: how i will make  String name bold  in each forloop itation and after final textview all element of "name" show bold???

Comment: only tell me after gett all string when load in textview how i will make this stringbold  "name "

Comment: You can also do this with HTML tags - [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191414/using-spannablestring-builder-and-rich-text) - just create regular strings like String name = <b>Name</b>; and when you setText on the textview like in that example tell it to recognize the HTML